# sort persian words in vue tables

Tags: sorting, vue.js, utf-8, farsi

In **utf-8** there are some characters that is not in Arabic like : `گ چ پ ژ` but in the Persian exists.

When I'm using **jd-vue-table** or any vue table, sorting is according to Arabic, and the specified characters are at last of the list. but **پ** that is not in Arabic is the 3rd characters in sort and sort of: `احمد,  پرهام,یزدان,` in Asc in action is: `احمد,یزدان,پرهام`.

( For easy to read: ahmad, parham, yazdan . **p** is like *پ** in Persian. and is 3rd but in sort appeared like this ahmad,yazdan,parham. It seems sorting is according to Arabic! )
Is there any way to config **utf-8** for correct persian characters sorting or create a custom  one to sort according to that?

Comment: Sort order depends on your locale, how have you configured that?

Comment: I just copy and paste codes from https://jamesdruhan.github.io/vue-jd-table/. I don't know how to locate. also I found some example :https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/persian but don't know how to use in sortSpecial option of vue-jd-table